# how to scrape id value using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[This is the html code what I want to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTi09.png)

My question is about scraping id value using beautifulsoup.

First, i do this

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html parser')

link = soup.find_all("li",{"id":re.compile("^goods")})
```

and then,

```
link.select_one('li[id^=goods]').get('id')
```

but it didn't work. Link doesn't have any function.

What I have to do to scrape all id values which name is `id="goods~"`??
Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

You need to do hierarchy scan. but if you just want all the text involved with goods use this.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
for elem in soup(text=re.compile(r' #\S{12}')):
    print elem.parent
```

Comment: Can i ask you what does #\S{12} means?
And i want to get id value.
For example, 5530013 6066396 5529981 ... in the image file.
Can i get a method to scrape that number??
I do not know much because I'm studying python for the first time. I'm sorry..

Comment: @안홍경 You can use Chrome Inspector to get the xPath. remember if you want to get all <li> values you must read the parent element <ul> and get all nested childs and there you can have more power manipulating elements and get all the values you want :)

Comment: @안홍경 If you are starting. I would recommend using PyQuery its simpler I use it myself. I don't use often BS because it makes too complex the data gathering.